# File upload validation in PHP

Tags: php, validation, security, file-upload

I'm using the following php code to upload a csv file. I want to use a good validation and not only via mime type or file extension. How can I do that?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $isfileok = false;
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    $isfileok = true;
    }
    if($isfileok){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What is good validation to you?

Comment: @Joni A validation that not can be easily bypassed. For example mime type can be changed if I intercepted the request. Also file extension can be changed from a malicious file extension to csv.

Comment: What is "valid" then? Do you want to ensure that only CSV files can be uploaded, and not PDFs jpgs or excel sheets for example? Do you want to scan the uploaded files for viruses, what?

Comment: What are you doing with these files that could make them a potential security risk? They're CSVs so don't execute them and don't store them with an arbitrary extension. It's not even like there are any weird features to most CSV parsers like there might be with XML or YAML.

Comment: I just want to make sure that it's a "CSV" file and not other thing

Comment: @Chris, I'm importing the csv file to mysql database.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no need to validate that if they are csv file or other thing?

Comment: A CSV is one of the most loosely defined file types there is. There is almost nothing that strictly makes a file either a CSV or not a CSV. The best you can probably do is check that for every line, there is the same number of fields on each.

Comment: But realistically, a CSV doesn't even have to contain commas or new lines (if it's only a single row and a single field).

Comment: You are right. The good thing is that I know how many cells should be in one row. other thing I can do is to go through each cell and make sure it does not have a php or html code or sql statements.
Thank you @Chris and Joni :)

Answer (score 1):

You can look for patterns within the file content to determine the type.  We solved this exact problem in a project I worked on using mime magic detection functionality in Tika.  https://tika.apache.org/1.1/detection.html